# Accessing GUI from another class

Tags: android, user-interface

xml code

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

java code

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        public LinearLayout layout;


        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);

            TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);
            int k = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++) {

                TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

                for (int j = 0; j < boardSize; j++) {

                    TextView cell = new TextView();
                    cell.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                    cell.setId(k);
                    k++;

                    cell.setHeight(20);
                    cell.setWidth(20);


                    row.addView(cell);

                }

                table.addView(row);
            }

            layout.addView(table);  

    }
```

What is the bast way to do `layout.findViewById(id).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);` from another class without getting “android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.” 
or 
"I/Choreographer(31253): Skipped X frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

```
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        move();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    layout.findViewById(id).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error 2 " + e);
                }
            }, 0, 300);
```

This is how i'm trying updating cells.

```
03-08 13:16:44.869: D/libEGL(677): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
03-08 13:16:44.889: D/libEGL(677): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_tegra.so
03-08 13:16:44.889: D/libEGL(677): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
03-08 13:16:44.919: D/OpenGLRenderer(677): Enabling debug mode 0
03-08 13:16:45.489: I/System.out(677): Error 1 android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
03-08 13:16:45.489: I/System.out(677): Error 1 android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
03-08 13:16:45.499: I/System.out(677): Error 1 android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Comment: Threads != classes.  There is nothing in the code you have shown, here, that would cause a WrongThread exception.  Please show the code that generates the exception.  ... and, btw, you can ignore the "skipped frames" message if you are seeing it in the emulator.  That's just the emulator being slow.

Comment: u can use `AsyncTask` for that for creating `views` in `doInBackground` method

Comment: @kaushik No, an AsyncTask is not the solution to this, if anything, it might be part of the problem.

Comment: Blake, there is no other code yet, I'm trying to segment MainActivity into couple of different classes (MVC model preferred) and also update 'cell' elements in the loop by the timer.

Comment: I can't ignore skipped frames because they kick in after ~2minutes and increase until the app freezes.

Comment: "and also update 'cell' elements in the loop by the timer" - there is your problem.  You cannot update the ui from the background, but must use one of the mechanism for pushing the updates themselves from the background context to the UI thread.

Comment: Btw, is there a better way to create all those UI elements (cells)? Is there a way to create the on not ui-thread?

Comment: @ChrisStratton : no.  You can see that OP is calling runOnUiThread.  He is not "updating the ui from the background".  OP, I repeat: this code is not throwing the exception you describe, nor is is freezing.  Where, for instance are you scheduling the timer?  How many of them are you scheduling?

Comment: G. Blake Meike, The "How many of them are you scheduling?" question, is very good question!!! The answer is: a lot, plus the number is increasing as app runs.

Answer (score 0):

You must be calling `layout.findViewById(id).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);` in some other place which is not UI thread.

You can pass your view object to that class which wants to set background color and do:

```
view.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
        });
```

Comment: can you please give the example how would you pass view object to the other class?

Comment: can you post all the code where you are calling setBackgroundColor()?  you can pass view object in constructor or as function parameter just like any other variable. but you can not call UI operations on other than UI thread.

Comment: what are you doing in `move()` function? is there any UI operation? can you post code.

Comment: no, move() increments the array elements, nothing to do with UI. This is why it's outside of "runOnUiThread".

Comment: in MainActivity you are already setting background color Black, in TimerTask also you are setting bg color as Black. Why? looks like there must be some code where you set bg color other than Black? PS: your time task code look correct to me.

Comment: yes, there is an array, based on which i'm updating the "cells" (layout.findViewById(id).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);) where "id" coming from the array. But all this irrelevant to the problem, since the code is working for 5 minutes and then app freezes(skipping frames problem), if i'm moving updates to the UI to different thread I get “android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.”

Comment: can you post stacktrace?

Comment: stack trace of above exception. Put `Log.e("TAG", "Error 2 ", e);`

Comment: http://crodrigues.com/updating-the-ui-from-a-background-thread-on-android/ and http://www.lucazanini.eu/2013/android/updating-frequently-a-textview-inside-a-loop/?lang=en looks like the solution to the problems i'm having... But i have tried both, and they didn't work for me.

Comment: Added stack trace to first post.

Comment: You *totally* cannot do this!  You will get a CalledFromWrongThreadException

Comment: are you sure the code you posted i.e. TimerTask is the one where you are getting exception. because your stacktrace give "Error 1" whereas you TimeTask has "Error 2".

Comment: yeah, it's "if" statement. errors 1, 2... are the same gui update -> layout.findViewById(id).setBackgroundColor(Color.COLOR_GOES_HERE);

Comment: G. Blake Meike, I figured.

Comment: Prakash, you are looking at the wrong place. The problems are: 1) to many updates to the UI 2) updating the UI from the separate thread 3) not correctly built UI. If you know how to solve any of those, without triggering the other, please let me know.